# Scrapy scrape content having same class name

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to crawl and scrape data from a particular webiste. The crawle works fine, but i'm having issue when scraping content having from div having same class name. As for example:

```
<div class="same_name">
 this is the 1st div
</div>
<div class="same_name">
 this is the 2nd div
</div>
<div class="same_name">
 this is the 3rd div
</div>
```

I want to retrieve only **this is the 1st div**. The code i've used is:

```
desc = hxs.select('//div[@class = "same_name"]/text()').extract()
```

But it returns me all the contents. Any help would be really helpful !!

Answer (score 1):

Ok , this one worked for me.

```
print desc[0]
```

It returned me **this is the first div** which is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use BeautifulSoup. Its a great html parser.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="same_name">
this is the 1st div
</div>
<div class="same_name">
this is the 2nd div
</div>
<div class="same_name">
this is the 3rd div
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
print soup.text
```

That should do the work.

Answer (score 0):

```
'(//div[@class = "same_name"])[1]/text()'
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `xpath` you will get all the div with the same class, further, you can loop on them to get the result(for scrapy):

```
divs = response.xpath('//div[@class="full class name"]')
for div in divs:
  if div.css("div.class"):
```